# Wildcard Subdomain in Nginx on Default EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, wildcard-subdomain, angular-fullstack

I'm using a default EC2 instance with no domain name registered. I'm attempting to test some multi-tenant functionality in a MEAN stack app using subdomains.

Basically I can access the site through the browser using a default AWS public DNS ex.

```
http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

That's all good and fine, it works OK.

The problem is that I want to enable the ability to access subdomains of that domain. So for example I want to be able to hit:

```
http://client1.ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
http://client2.ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
etc.
```

I can't figure out how to do this using nginx. Here's my current nginx default file:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name *.ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

However when I navigate to any subdomain I get an error saying the webpage is not available.

If I access it without a subdomain the page loads just fine.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Appreciate any help!

EDIT: You will notice that I've created a proxy pass because I have my node server running using forever on port 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Amazon does not create wildcard records for their EC2 domains, so the *. addresses aren't even going to resolve (you can easily test this). You would instead need to register a domain and have it wildcarded as a CNAME to your EC2 instance.

Comment: Oh no! I was afraid of that. Is there anyway around this without having to register a domain?

Comment: Ended up doing a subdomain of a subdomain: *.dev.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the default amazonaws hostname, but there is another way.

See http://xip.io.

`any.subdomain.you-like.x.x.x.x.xip.io` will automatically resolve to the IP address `x.x.x.x`, so if you substitute your EC2 instance's IP address in the hostname, you have what you need, here.

For clarity: I'm not affiliated with this service.